# How to create tableview like iphone ringtone setting?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I am new to xcode and obj-c and creating my first iphone app. Right now, I am trying to display 2 NSMUTABLEARRAY data to TABLE VIEW, they are Name and Level. I want to display it like iphone's ringtones setting style:
john    1 >
Kate    2 >
... so on
level is a value of 1-5 and editable. When user tap on certain row, let say tap on kate, it will display :
      1
✓   2
      3
      4
      5
and i can change the value of level by taping it and store new value to corresponding array. So let say i tap 5, the table will change too:

john    1 >
Kate    5 >
... so on
How do i do that?? Or is there any tutorial that closely show how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of useful tutorials here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uitableview

Comment: Is it 'accessory views'? the thing that im trying to achieve